# Input blur and window blur

Tags: jquery, forms, input, focus, blur

So I have this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/KDAM8/), and am trying to figure out how to make the input retain it's value on the window's blur. When you focus on an input, then alt+tab out, or click on another screen, then return, it doesn't keep the correct value. Not only am I having a tough time understanding why this happens, I'm having a tough time explaining it. Hopefully you can understand what I'm asking with the jsFiddle.

```
<input type="text" value="name" />
<input type="password" value="password" />​
```

```
$('input').each(function() {
    var itemVal;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        itemVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        $(this).val(itemVal);
    });
});​
```

Comment: What else did you expect `$(this).val(itemVal)` to do? Your code is overwriting the input fields because that's what you clearly and explicitly told it to do.

Comment: Right, but my question is how I can maintain the input's original value? It's fine if you blur within the page, but not when you blur by focusing another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving on gotuskar's approach: If you cache each field's initial value in the element's `.data`, you can compare it to the existing value on both focus and blur to get the desired effect:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).data('itemVal', $(this).val());

    $(this).focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === $(this).data('itemVal')) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
            $(this).val($(this).data('itemVal'));
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/KDAM8/1/

Comment: Perfect. Does exactly what I need it to. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Debug and try to understand the change I made -

```
$('input').each(function() {
    var itemVal;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        itemVal = $(this).val();
        if (itemVal === 'name' || itemVal === 'password') // added
          $(this).val('');
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        itemVal = $(this).val(); // added
        if (itemVal !== 'name' || itemVal === 'password') // added
            $(this).val(itemVal);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Which will work fine on the `name` field, and fail completely on the `password` field.

Comment: Agree, it was just a fix to make him understand one aspect, and let him understand and code for `password`

Comment: Now that does it for `password` too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd like it a little more generalized, as it won't be for just these two fields. Thanks though!

Comment: Definitely @Blazemonger answer is more elegant. That was one of the solution.